Unable to get turtle2/pose data using subscriber callback ROS2 Turtlesim
I am using Turtlesim in ROS2. But I am unable to get pose data of turtle2 using pt_pose_callback function which is subscribed to /turtle2/pose . I have checked on Terminal and I am able to get data on /turtle2/pose but not inside the code.
Here's my code
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy 
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.executors import MultiThreadedExecutor
from rclpy.callback_groups import MutuallyExclusiveCallbackGroup,ReentrantCallbackGroup
from turtlesim.srv import Spawn,Kill
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from turtlesim.msg import Pose
import numpy as np
import random 
import math
import time

class RobberTurtle(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("robber_turtle")
        self.get_logger().info("RT node has been started")

        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.current_x = 0.0
        self.current_y = 0.0
        self.current_theta = 0.0
        self.goal_x = 0.0
        self.goal_y = 0.0
        self.rt_x = 0.0
        self.rt_y = 0.0
        self.rt_theta = 0.0

        self.linear_vel = 5.0
        self.radius = 5.0
        self.angular_vel = self.linear_vel / self.radius

        # Noise Parameters
        self.std_dev = 3.0

        self.circle_timer = self.create_timer(0.01,self.make_circles)       
        self.create_timer(5.0,self.pose_publisher)

    def set_class_instance(self, class_pt_instance):
        self.pt = class_pt_instance
        # Subscribers
        self.create_subscription(Pose,"turtle1/pose",self.pose_callback,10) 
        self.create_subscription(Pose,"rt_real_pose",self.rt_pose_callback,10) 

        # Timers & Publishers
        self.twist_pub = self.create_publisher(Twist,"turtle1/cmd_vel",10)
        self.pose_pub = self.create_publisher(Pose,"rt_real_pose",10)
        self.noisy_pose_pub = self.create_publisher(Pose,"rt_noisy_pose",10)

               
    def make_circles(self):
        self.twist_msg = Twist()
        self.v = self.linear_vel
        self.r = self.radius
        self.w = self.angular_vel

        self.twist_msg.linear.x = self.r * self.w
        self.twist_msg.angular.z = self.w
        self.twist_pub.publish(self.twist_msg)
    
    # Subscriber callback to obtain pose data of RT after 5 seconds
    def rt_pose_callback(self,msg):
        # print("Got Pose")
        self.rt_x = msg.x 
        self.rt_y = msg.y 
        self.rt_theta = msg.theta

        if abs(self.rt_x - self.pt.pt_x) <= 0.5 and abs(self.rt_y - self.pt.pt_y) <= 0.5:
            self.get_logger().info("Caught!!!")
            self.circle_timer.cancel()

        self.set_motion_parameters()

    # Obtain Circular motion parameters
    def set_motion_parameters(self):
        self.get_logger().info("Setting motion parameters")

        # Equation to Calculate Pose of Turtle after 5 seconds
        theta = self.rt_theta + self.angular_vel * 5.0
        self.goal_x = 10.0#self.radius * math.cos(theta)
        self.goal_y = 2.0#self.radius * math.sin(theta)
        self.get_logger().info(f"Goal set to x: {self.goal_x}, y: {self.goal_y}")

    def pose_callback(self,msg):
        self.current_x = msg.x 
        self.current_y = msg.y 
        self.current_theta = msg.theta

        if not self.pt.spawned and time.time() - self.start_time >= 10.0:
            self.pt.spawned = True
            self.pt.timer = self.create_timer(0.01,self.pt.reach_goal) 
            self.pt.spawn_turtle()
            

    # Publish pose of Current turtle
    def pose_publisher(self):
        msg = Pose()
        msg.x = self.current_x
        msg.y = self.current_y
        msg.theta = self.current_theta
        msg.linear_velocity = self.twist_msg.linear.x
        msg.angular_velocity = self.twist_msg.angular.z
        self.pose_pub.publish(msg)

        noise_x = self.gaussian_noise(self.current_x)
        noise_y = self.gaussian_noise(self.current_y)
        noise_theta = self.gaussian_noise(self.current_theta)

        msg.x = noise_x
        msg.y = noise_y
        msg.theta = noise_theta
        self.noisy_pose_pub.publish(msg)

    def gaussian_noise(self,x,mean=0.0,std_dev=3.0):
        noise = np.random.normal(mean, std_dev)
        noisy_pose = x + noise
        return noisy_pose
    


class PoliceTurtle(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("police_turtle")
        self.get_logger().info(" PT Node has been started")
        # Declare PID params
        self.declare_parameters(
            namespace='',
            parameters=[
                ('linear_x_max', 2.0),
                ('linear_y_max', 2.0),
                ('linear_x_min', -2.0),
                ('linear_y_min', -2.0),
                ('angular_z_max', 2.0),
                ('angular_z_min', -2.0),
                ('kp_linear_x', 5.0),
                ('ki_linear_x', 0.0),
                ('kd_linear_x', 0.0),
                ('kp_linear_y', 0),
                ('ki_linear_y', 0.0),
                ('kd_linear_y', 0.0),
                ('kp_angular', 10.5), # 3.0
                ('ki_angular', 0.0),
                ('kd_angular', 0.0),
                ('linear_acceleration', 2.0),
                ('linear_deceleration', 2.0),
                ('angular_acc',1.0)  
                ]
        )
        self.linear_x_max = self.get_parameter('linear_x_max').value
        self.linear_y_max = self.get_parameter('linear_y_max').value
        self.linear_x_min = self.get_parameter('linear_x_min').value
        self.linear_y_min = self.get_parameter('linear_y_min').value
        self.angular_z_max = self.get_parameter('angular_z_max').value
        self.angular_z_min = self.get_parameter('angular_z_min').value
        self.kp_linear_x = self.get_parameter('kp_linear_x').value
        self.ki_linear_x = self.get_parameter('ki_linear_x').value
        self.kd_linear_x = self.get_parameter('kd_linear_x').value
        self.kp_linear_y = self.get_parameter('kp_linear_y').value
        self.ki_linear_y = self.get_parameter('ki_linear_y').value
        self.kd_linear_y = self.get_parameter('kd_linear_y').value
        self.kp_angular = self.get_parameter('kp_angular').value
        self.ki_angular = self.get_parameter('ki_angular').value
        self.kd_angular = self.get_parameter('kd_angular').value
        self.max_linear_acc = self.get_parameter('linear_acceleration').value
        self.max_linear_dec = self.get_parameter('linear_deceleration').value
        self.max_angular_acc = self.get_parameter('angular_acc').value

        self.int_error_theta = 0
        self.prev_error_theta = 0
        self.int_error_x = 0
        self.prev_error_x = 0
        self.int_error_y = 0
        self.prev_error_y = 0

        self.pt_x = 0.0
        self.pt_y = 0.0
        self.pt_theta = 0.0
        self.goal_x = 0.0
        self.goal_y = 0.0
        self.curr_lin_vel = 0.0
        self.curr_ang_vel = 0.0
        self.prev_lin_vel = 0.0
        self.prev_ang_vel = 0.0
        self.spawned = False

        # Client
        self.cli = self.create_client(Spawn,"spawn")
        while not self.cli.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
            self.get_logger().info('Spawn service not available, waiting again...')

        # Subscribers
        self.cb_renter = ReentrantCallbackGroup()
        self.create_subscription(Pose,"/turtle2/pose",self.pt_pose_callback,10,callback_group=self.cb_renter) 
        # Timers & Publishers   
        self.twist_pub = self.create_publisher(Twist,"turtle2/cmd_vel",10)

    def set_class_instance(self, class_rt_instance):
        self.rt = class_rt_instance

    # Timer function to execute the goal
    def reach_goal(self):
        print("In here")
        if self.spawned:
            
            msg = Twist()
            dt = 0.01 # According to Hz of Topic publishing
            dist_x = self.rt.goal_x - self.pt_x
            dist_y = self.rt.goal_y - self.pt_y
            print("Goal" + str(dist_x) + " , " + str(dist_y))
            print(self.pt_x)
            distance = math.sqrt(dist_x * dist_x + dist_y * dist_y)
            goal_theta = math.atan2(dist_y,dist_x)

            # Adjust Linear velocity
            self.curr_lin_vel = abs(self.pid_controller(distance, self.prev_error_x, self.int_error_x, self.kp_linear_x, self.ki_linear_x, self.kd_linear_x, dt))

            # Apply linear acceleration constraints
            linear_acc = (self.curr_lin_vel - self.prev_lin_vel) / dt
            if linear_acc > self.max_linear_acc:
                linear_acc = self.max_linear_acc
            elif linear_acc < -self.max_linear_acc:
                linear_acc = -self.max_linear_acc

            # Adjust Orientation
            goal_theta = math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x)
            diff = goal_theta - self.pt_theta
            if diff > math.pi:
                diff -= 2 * math.pi
            elif diff < -math.pi:
                diff += 2 * math.pi

            # # Apply linear acceleration constraints
            # angular_acc = (self.curr_ang_vel - self.prev_ang_vel) / dt
            # if angular_acc > self.max_angular_acc:
            #     angular_acc = self.max_angular_acc
            # elif angular_acc < -self.max_angular_acc:
            #     angular_acc = -self.max_angular_acc

            if distance < 1.0:
                # Acceleratin<
                print("Reached")
                # Update msg with the current velocities
                msg.linear.x = 0.0
                msg.angular.z = 0.0
                self.timer.cancel()

            elif distance <= 3.0 and distance >= 1.0:
                # Decelerating
                self.prev_lin_vel = self.max_linear_dec
                self.curr_lin_vel = self.prev_lin_vel - linear_acc * dt
                msg.linear.x = self.curr_lin_vel
                msg.angular.z = self.pid_controller(diff,self.prev_error_theta,self.int_error_theta,self.kp_angular,self.ki_angular,self.kd_angular,dt)
                print("---------------")

            else:
                print("Here")
                self.curr_lin_vel = self.prev_lin_vel + linear_acc * dt
                msg.linear.x = self.curr_lin_vel
                msg.angular.z = self.pid_controller(diff,self.prev_error_theta,self.int_error_theta,self.kp_angular,self.ki_angular,self.kd_angular,dt)
             
            # Update previous errors and velocities
            self.prev_error_x = distance
            self.prev_lin_vel = self.curr_lin_vel

            self.twist_pub.publish(msg)
        
    # PID Controller template
    def pid_controller(self, error, previous_error, int_error, kp, ki, kd, dt):
        control_action = kp * error + ki * int_error + kd * ((error - previous_error) / dt)
        return control_action
    
    def pt_pose_callback(self,msg):
        self.pt_x = msg.x 
        self.pt_y = msg.y 
        self.pt_theta = msg.theta

    def spawn_turtle(self):
        self.req = Spawn.Request()
        self.start_x = random.uniform(1.0,10.0)
        self.start_y = random.uniform(1.0,10.0)
        self.start_theta = random.uniform(0,3.14)

        self.req.x = self.start_x
        self.req.y = self.start_y
        self.req.theta = self.start_theta
        self.req.name = "turtle2"  # Ensure this is a string
        self.future = self.cli.call_async(self.req)
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, self.future)
        if self.future.result() is not None:
            self.get_logger().info(f'Successfully spawned {self.future.result().name}')
        else:
            self.get_logger().info('Failed to spawn turtle')


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    rt = RobberTurtle()
    pt = PoliceTurtle()
    rt.set_class_instance(pt)
    pt.set_class_instance(rt)

    executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()
    executor.add_node(rt)
    executor.add_node(pt)
    executor.spin()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


           
```           


Please try to reduce your code to a minimal reproducible example. You might actually find the issue yourself in that process.
